# How to convert Sun Oct 25 18:41:35 IST 2015 to Oct 25 2015 in java?

Tags: java

I have to convert the date `Sun Oct 25 18:41:35 IST 2015` into `Oct 25 2015` in java.
Any one can you please suggest?

Comment: another 'homework for me' question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
java.util.Date date = new Date("Sun Oct 25 18:41:35 IST 2015");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
String format = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```